# Android AlarmClock ACTION_SET_ALARM intent produces exception

Tags: android, alarm

The given example produces an Exception (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent)

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "New Alarm"); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hours); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, mins); 
startActivity(i);
```

on my SGS2 Android Version 2.3.3. Do you have any ideas, what can be going wrong? An another intent request (e.g. selecting a contact from the address book) works fine.

Thank you,
Artjom

Comment: Look at this question [Android AlarmClock causing force close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571768/android-alarmclock-causing-force-close/8571916#8571916), I think its same as yours, and Also look at the answer, is it solved your problem? If that answer solved your problem then please let me know..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do you have any ideas, what can be going wrong?

The device does not support that activity. This is not unheard of. Either catch the exception and let the user know, or use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to see if anything will respond to your `Intent` in advance of calling `startActivity()`.

Comment: Is this is a vendor specific behavior? The same activities can also work with some devices and do not with other?

Answer (score 10):

You need to set permission in manifest file also.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
```

Comment: my apps force close when set alarm, and solved with add this permission, thanks